# How to make GIF animate on scroll only?

Tags: jquery, scroll, gif, animated-gif

I am building a Wordpress site that incorporates an animated GIF and I am trying to get the GIF to animate *only* when the user is scrolling.

The page is basically ready – http://www.fi1000.com/wp/ – but the GIF would work a lot better if it's only animating on window scroll.

I am just wondering if anyone out there might have an idea for a jQuery or CSS3 fix to achieve this? Not looking for the GIF to do anything except to *not* animate unless the user is scrolling.

The plugin I'm using to make the GIF move positions on scroll is called Skrollr https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Thanks for reading!

Comment: is that Pops from regular show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript and display a static image when stationary, then switch to the animated image during the onScroll event.

Comment: Great idea, thanks Lance! Any idea what that function would look like? Basically just a function that says "if window is scrolling, replace this img src". (I'm a total jQuery novice and wasn't able to find a solution from Googling) Thanks again Lance!

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than could be explained in a comment, @user2048638.  If you think the idea will work for you, go ahead and accept this answer then give it a try.  Once you have some code written, post a new question and we can help you in greater detail.  If you Google jquery onScroll you can find working examples.